# How to keep user authentication state securely in the frontend, or is it possible?

Tags: angular, security, authentication, browser, frontend

I am currently trying to implement an easy version of authentication. I do not want to use JWT or other stuff. The user will send a verification code to the backend when logging in to the system. Then backend will only return true or false to indicate whether authentication has successed. And I want the user to be in the authenticated state for a period of time. How to achieve this functionality without sending any other request to the backend. I know I can store something in the cookies or localstorage or sessionstorage, and check those places for authentication information. But the user can access those places and manually change something, right? So it is not safe. Is it possible to keep the user's authentication state only in the frontend, but with some level of security?Thanks!

Comment: HttpOnly cookies aren't readable by JavaScript, so that's one option.

Comment: Short story, never trust the client, only trust the server. Also you are exactly describing the JWT, why not use it?

Comment: @Brandon Is it possible to insert HttpOnly cookies manually by go to developer tool of the browser?

Comment: @Ploppy Just exploring the possibility not using it

Comment: @YouZhou it's possible to create a cookie using Chrome dev tools for example, but I don't think you can set the HttpOnly flag that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to common belief, you **can** actually store state on the client, reasonably securely for many purposes. This is what frameworks like Rails do by default, the whole user session (all session data) is saved in a cookie if not set otherwise. It is not straightforward though, and it's not something you should ever implement yourself.

It is also true that anything on the client is fully controlled by the potentially malicious user. Well, unless proper protections are in place.

The key to this is **message authentication** and/or **encryption** (note that the latter does not necessarily imply the former, these are different things).

You can mentally model things like the server sends itself a message (the session state, which it doesn't want to remember between two requests), and the server wants to make sure that the message is (1) not changed during transfer through the client (message authentication), and (2) kept secret if necessary (encryption).

For this to work, both sender and receiver need to have a shared secret. As sender and receiver in this case are the same (the server), it only means there needs to be a secret stored for your application. In Rails for example, this is derived from SECRET_KEY_BASE. Once you have this, anything sent to the client for storage can be encrypted if necessary and a message authentication code (MAC) can be generated to ensure the properties above. Practically speaking, you could have session management code to generate a HMAC with your application secret, add that to the cookie, and have your application check the MAC to make sure the cookie was not tampered with. If you also need encryption (secrecy of the state stored on the client), you may want to choose an authenticated encryption (like for example AES-GCM) which provides both properties in one go.

There is a small problem though. Let's say you have a session state encrypted, authenticated and stored on the client. The session state includes roles for a user. You have a user whom you give admin rights. Your user is smart enough and saves his cookie for later. You then change your mind, and revoke admin from this user. If he sends his old cookie which *did* have admin, nothing will keep him from becoming an admin. This is called a **replay** attack, and if it is a problem in your application, you have to implement protection manually.

Also let's say two of your applications use the same secret for whatever reason (a bad idea in general, but anyway). An encrypted cookie from one can potentially be used in the other, which may wreck havoc or lead to vulnerabilities if not handled correctly.

Now with all of this discussed with potential challenges, please note that this is **exactly** what JWT solves for you (with HMAC), or JWE for the encrypted case. Unless just learning about these things, please just use a standard JWT/JWE implementation, because it's not straightforward to get these things right, and implementation details matter a lot.

Comment: Another question, for JWT authentication we don't have to use username and password pattern right? Can I use email and verification code pattern and when the code got verified, just use the email id as payload?

Comment: Look at jwt as a way to store data on the client in a way that it is protected from tampering (but not encrypted!) by default. It can be any data, and yes, you can use it as an id token too, for example the `sub` field can hold the email address. As long as the secret to produce the HMAC is stored securely on the server, nobody can easily produce a valid jwt for your application. It is also protected from replay and some other attacks in correct implementations.